# check number of dots in file and append string in the same line after

Tags: python

hello guys im trying to figure this out but im completly stuck.
i have a text file. this text file contains as IP's.

file:

```
host 192.168.12.1 <- missing the subnetmask
```

now what i want to solve is. that the programm read the lines and detects the combination between characters and numbers and should attach the subnetmask after the ip the “255. 255. 255. 255"

I know you can solve the problem with regex, but I’m so lost I know not at all how to start.

result in txt file should be:

```
host 192.168.12.1 255.255.255.255
```

my try:

```
import re

with open("test.txt","r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("test.txt","r") as f:
    for line in lines:
        match = re.match(r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", line)
        if match:
            f.append(" 255.255.255.255") <- should write in same LINE
            print("yey")
        else:
           pass
```

Comment: It would help, if you describe, where you got stuck at the moment. For example: (a) matches also line `host 192.168.12.1 255.255.255.255` (with second IP) but should __only match__ `host 192.168.12.1` (without second IP = subnet mask). In other words give us __positive and negative test-cases__.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate string like this:

```
a = "Hello"
b = "World"
c = a + " " + b
print(c)
```

In your case :

```
if match:
            line  + " " + "255.255.255.255" 
            print("yey")
        else:
           pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Use re.findall and rstrip()

```
import re

with open("test.txt","r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("test1.txt","w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line.rstrip())
        matches = re.findall(r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", line)
        if len(matches) == 1:
            f.write(" 255.255.255.255")
        f.write("\n")
```